# How do I get the IPAddress in Cordova apps

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, cordova-plugins

I am working on upgrading my MFP app from 7.1 to 8.0  and one of issue identified by the migrate script is that the WL getNetworkInfo() API is discontinue and  I have to used Cordova network info plugin

However, I don't see a method in the Cordova Plugin class to to get the Ip address

Here is call I make in IBM MFP 7.1:

```
WL.Device.getNetworkInfo(function (networkInfo) {
alert (networkInfo.ipAddress);  
});
```

How do i get the IP in Cordova apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This repo looks very promising https://github.com/salbahra/cordova-plugin-networkinterface.

```
//CLI
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-networkinterface

//JS
networkinterface.getIPAddress(function (ip) { alert(ip); });
```